# How to use union on YII

Tags: php, yii

i want to upgrade from php into  YII but i stuck this problem. This is code

`

```
select  h.Kelas_ID KelasAlias, h.Ruangan_ID RuanganAlias, j.Jadwal_ID, j.Ruangan_ID, j.Kelas_ID, c.Kelas, r.Ruangan 
From kehadiran h LEFT join jadwal j on h.Guru_ID = j.Guru_ID and h.Kelas_ID = j.Kelas_ID and h.Ruangan_ID = j.Ruangan_ID
left join kelas c on c.Kelas_ID=h.Kelas_ID 
LEFT join ruangan r on r.Ruangan_ID=h.Ruangan_ID
where h.Guru_ID = '1'
group by c.Kelas_ID, r.Ruangan_ID 
union all
SELECT  j.Kelas_ID KelasAlias, j.Ruangan_ID RuanganAlias, j.Jadwal_ID, j.Ruangan_ID, j.Kelas_ID, c.Kelas, r.Ruangan 
FROM jadwal j LEFT JOIN kelas c ON c.Kelas_ID=j.Kelas_ID 
LEFT JOIN ruangan r ON r.Ruangan_ID=j.Ruangan_ID  
WHERE j.Guru_ID = '1'
GROUP BY c.Kelas_ID, r.Ruangan_ID
```

`

But now how to use union in YII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use findAllBySql and get the resultu using  the sql query you prefere

```
 $yourQuery = "select  h.Kelas_ID KelasAlias, h.Ruangan_ID RuanganAlias,      
     j.Jadwal_ID, j.Ruangan_ID, j.Kelas_ID, c.Kelas, r.Ruangan 
     From kehadiran h LEFT join jadwal j on h.Guru_ID = j.Guru_ID 
     and h.Kelas_ID = j.Kelas_ID and h.Ruangan_ID = j.Ruangan_ID
     left join kelas c on c.Kelas_ID=h.Kelas_ID 
     LEFT join ruangan r on r.Ruangan_ID=h.Ruangan_ID
     where h.Guru_ID = '1'
     group by c.Kelas_ID, r.Ruangan_ID 
     union all
    SELECT  j.Kelas_ID KelasAlias, j.Ruangan_ID RuanganAlias, j.Jadwal_ID,    
    j.Ruangan_ID, j.Kelas_ID, c.Kelas, r.Ruangan 
    FROM jadwal j LEFT JOIN kelas c ON c.Kelas_ID=j.Kelas_ID 
    LEFT JOIN ruangan r ON r.Ruangan_ID=j.Ruangan_ID  
    WHERE j.Guru_ID = '1'
    GROUP BY c.Kelas_ID, r.Ruangan_ID "


$results =YourModel::model()->findAllBySql( $yourQuery);
```